# Can a smartphone's accelerometer be used for tuning instruments?

Tags: tuning

Similar to a clip-on tuner, the vibrations of the instrument itself will be detected instead of its sound.
Procedure:

1. Phone is held where it can sense vibrations of the instrument
2. Play the instrument
3. Tune according to vibration Hz displayed.

Will this be reliable?

Comment: This seems like a tech question rather than a musical one, and I imagine the answer is that phone accelerometer's are nowhere near that sensitive (or if they were, it might vary by model). After all, a device which measures how it is vibrated by sound waves... is a microphone, and they all have one of those.

Comment: Getting a clip on transducer that plugs into your phone seems like an easier way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an intersection of acoustics and technology, not music.

Comment: I will say, though: There's an underlying confusion. What's proposed is *not* like a clip-on tuner; the clip-on is a type of pickup, measuring the vibrations of a solid object. If you hold something near a sound source, you're measuring sound waves in air. This will almost always be *less* reliable, simply because you're likely to get contamination from other sound sources.

Comment: @AndyBonner "Phone is held where it can sense vibrations of the instrument" doesn't really rule out pressing the phone against instrument.

Comment: Why not just try it out?  I"m not aware of any tool that will report the accelerometer values at anything close to the 2 - 10 kHz rate you'd need and I rather doubt the accelerometer itself responds at that rate.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft as an example, the Bosch accelerometer datasheets under https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/motion-sensors/accelerometers/ list bandwidths from 800 Hz to 1600 Hz, which is already enough open guitar strings. The BMA400 even has antialiasing filter.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, but not for long. At the time of writing this, the maximum accelerometer sampling rates are unspecified and may extend to audio frequencies, but Android 12 will limit the sample rate to 200 Hz to prevent using the accelerometer as microphone. This prevents the accelerometer from detecting frequencies above 100 Hz, or G2.

Comment: A nit: yes that's the Nyquist limit, but when you add the digital sampling quantization of amplitude the limit gets even lower.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft do you mean antialiasing filter? A properly designed ADC would filter out frequencies above Nyquist frequency before sampling and the filter amplitude response would start dropping well below it, but I haven't seen any sensor actually do that. I don't really understand how quantization would affect frequency response.